# Toad: Run plsql query without Bind Variables popup?

Tags: oracle11g, toad, toad-data-point

In SQL Developer this script returns the expected resultset:

```
define FromDate = '02-03-2019';
define ToDate = '02-05-2019';

select * from TEST_TABLE
where  test_date >= to_date('&&FromDate', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
and    test_date < to_date('&&ToDate', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

This same query does not run in Toad; it generates `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` error.

My question is, how can I run this query in Toad Data Point without adding more lines of codes and without having to re-enter the values in the `Bind Variables` popup?

Comment: This is a 'continuation' of your question yesterday. In reply I indicated that 'define' is an sqlplus directive, which SQL Developer understands. Unfortunately, Toad does not. Recall my point that you must always keep in the app (tool) your statements are directed and what is valid for them.

Answer (score 0):

Query like this

```
select * 
from TEST_TABLE
where test_date >= to_date(:FromDate, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
  and test_date <  to_date(:ToDate  , 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

runs OK in my TOAD 12.5.

Note that both variables should be VARCHAR2 (as you're `TO_DATE`-ing them), entered in `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

Comment: Thanks, but it generates the same `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`. Besides being `VARCHAR2` how do you declare `FromDate` and `ToDate` in Toad for that particular example?

Comment: Can you include the complete example, with the variable declarations?

Comment: That IS a complete example. Ctrl+F9 runs it, opening a window which lets you enter variables' values.

Comment: The reason for declaring the variables was to avoid the `Bind Variables` popup. But I guess it's my fault for not mentioning that in the post, so I'll edit.

Comment: Aha. See if this helps. Link is http://dev.toadfordataanalyst.com/webhelp/Content/Editor/Set_Bind_Variables.htm, scroll down to "To store a value for a bind variable". A quote: "... when you execute a SQL statement containing that bind variable, Toad will not prompt you for a value ...". HTH.